# Advanced text replacement

Tags: search, find, text

How can I replace a text in all files in all subfolders when my search includes "*"
for example I have many text files containing such pattern (some wrong paths that I want to correct)

```
/folder1/(abc)/params.launch
/folder2/(efd)/gui.launch
/folder3/(ghi)/robot.launch
```

Now I want to add /launch before each file to have such a result

```
/folder1/(abc)/launch/params.launch
/folder2/(efd)/launch/gui.launch
/folder3/(ghi)/launch/robot.launch
```

I thought about searching for the string pattern

> `")/*.launch"`

but then how can I replace it while keeping the content of those "*"

Comment: Its unclear to me..you want to create an intermediate directory `launch` inside existing directories and move the files ending with `.launch` there? or something else?

Comment: I have text files containing paths and they are wrong, I want to find a way to correct them automatically

Comment: So is the additional path component always `/launch`, or do you want to take each file's dot extension, and use **that** as an additional (variable) path component?

Comment: In this particular case it is always /launch but having a conditional assignment would also be interesting (depending on the extension, putting a different folder name which doesn't have to be the same as the extension)

Answer (score 2):

Should be fairly simple with `sed`:

```
sed 's;\([^/]*.launch$\);launch/\1;'
```

- You can group matched text by surrounding the expression in brackets (`\( ... \)`). You need to escape the parentheses to make `sed` see them as special syntax.
- The groups can be referred to using the position - the first group is `\1`, the second is `\2`, etc.

Example output:

```
$ sed 's;\([^/]*.launch\);launch/\1;' foo   
/folder1/(abc)/launch/params.launch
/folder2/(efd)/launch/gui.launch
/folder3/(ghi)/launch/robot.launch
```

This is for Basic Regular Expressions. For Extended Regular expressions, one can use `sed -r`, in which case the parentheses need not be escaped:

```
sed -r 's;([^/]*.launch);launch/\1;'
```

Lastly, in `sed`, and some other tools, the complete matched text can be referred to using `&`, avoiding the need for groups and backreferences altogether:

```
sed 's;[^/]*.launch;launch/&;' foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  ini="${line%/*}"
  last="${line##*/}"
  repl="${line##*.}"
      echo "${ini}/${repl}/${last}"
done <file.txt
```

**Output :**

```
/folder1/(abc)/launch/params.launch
/folder2/(efd)/launch/gui.launch
/folder3/(ghi)/launch/robot.launch
```

Here we have used the [parameter substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) of `bash` to have three variables:

- The `ini` variable will contain the part before last `/` e.g. `/folder1/(abc)`
- The `last` variable will contain the part after last `/` e.g. `params.launch`
- The `repl` variable will contain what to be put inside the `ini` and `last` variables i.e. `launch`

Then we have printed the values of the variables in the specified pattern puting `/` between them.